# Related Transaction ID's

Tags: paypal

I'm looking for a way to see which Transaction ID's are related to each other.

Just to clarify what I mean, when you search in your account in the Activity overview for a certain ID, it shows all related ID's as well. I want this relationship to be visible in a downloadable form (.csv/.xlsx/.pdf).

Perhaps with the help of API this could be achieved?

As far as I can see, there is no report available (for download) that shows relationships.

Answer (score 0):

- In the account go to Activity -> Reports -> All Reports -> Activity Download ([live](https://www.paypal.com/reports/dlog), [sandbox](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/reports/dlog))
- Select Transaction Type: All transactions, and the desired date range.
- "Create Report" and download when finished.
- There are two columns with IDs, "Transaction ID" and "Reference Txn ID". There is also a "Type" column.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply, but unfortunately this does not answer my question. What I would like to know is how "Transaction ID's" are related to each other.

For example, when making a purchase PayPal usually creates multiple Transaction ID's with different types such as "Authorization to", "Temporary hold", "Purchase from", etc. 

When looking up one of these ID's in PayPal, you can actually see the related other ID's. But when you make a download, this connection is not visible.

Comment: In the records for the capture and the refund, see the Reference Txn ID column for related IDs